# WPF Child Windows problem in Windows XP

Tags: wpf, windows-xp

I have written a WPF program that when user  clicked a button, a new window will be popped up.

I have tried to show the new window by using **Show()** or **ShowDialog()** function.

In **Windows 7**, when user closed the child window, the main window will remain and the program will not exit. This behavior is what I want to have.

However, when the program is run in **Windows XP**, when user closed the child window, the main window will be closed together and the whole program will be exited.

I have tried to set different value in different properties in Window class, finally, I found that the program will not exit only when I set the property **"ShowInTaskbar" to "False"** in child window.

However, if ShowInTaskbar is set to false, user cannot find the entry in task bar which is not the behavior that I want.

What I want to have is really simple. I just want the program running in Windows XP to have the same behavior as the program running in Windows 7 when user closed the child window (i.e. **main window will not exit when user closed the child window**). Also, I want to have an entry in task bar for a newly created child window(i.e. **ShowInTaskbar = true**).

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="ChildWindowTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Click="OpenChild">Open Child Window</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code For MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenChild(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildWindow child = new ChildWindow();
        child.Owner = this;
        //child.ShowInTaskbar = false; <--- if comment, the program will exit, when child window closed
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

**Child Window:**

```
<Window x:Class="ChildWindowTest.ChildWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ChildWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

**Code for Child Window:**

```
public partial class ChildWindow : Window
{
    public ChildWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add simple code that reproduce this problem? I've used both XP and WIN7, and never seen such behavior... Try creating very simple project with a parent and child window, see if it happens there

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution at all, but you always can subscribe to Closing event in **Application** class and cancel application closing in an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Did u make sure you have `childWindow.Owner` set as our MainWindow correctly before calling `childWindow.ShowDialog()`?